# Custom Controls don't render MenuStrip

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am currently tasked with making an application to manage children with special needs.

Long story short I am trying to make frames appear inside a frame. Internal Frames like in Java.

I succeeded in this but my frames MenuStrip disappears when I run the program. At first they were there but as soon as I put the frame in focus or move it around the MenuStrip disappears. It doesn't return. Even after I stopped the application and started it again, the strip is still gone.

However as seen on this picture the strip is clearly there in design view:

[image]

as opposed to this picture of the program running:

[image]

I wanted to set up the application to show off to my client to make sure they are happy with the look it currently got so I made this simple code for when I press a button in the parent frame menustrip:

```
private void plejebarnToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stamdataframe = new StamDataFrame();
        stamdataframe.MdiParent = this;
        stamdataframe.Show();
    }
```

The MenuStrip is placed in a custom control that is placed in it's parent frame. That frame becomes a child of the main parent frame that runs the application.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why is this tagged WPF?

Comment: @HighCore Good question. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the [AllowMerge property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.allowmerge%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on your MenuStrip is being set to true somewhere along the way.

You state that your frame becomes a child of the main parent frame that runs the application.  Therefore, with **AllowMerge=true**, the menu items will get added to the parent's menu.  From your second screenshot, it looks like that is exactly what's happening.

Comment: Oh. You are right, they do seem to be added to the main menu strip. I'll check about the AllowMerge property and report back.

Comment: Yes that seemed to do the trick just setting AllowMerge to false. Thank you!